# Server side validation for 'active' games

Tags: validation

Let's say I make a simple Snake game, and on top of that adds a highscore function.

What would be the best way to make sure that the players can't cheat their scores? The most straightforward way I can think of this is, well, just make sure to validate everything, or at least simulate the game on the server. Pressed right? Well, your snake moves right and stuff.

Is this sort of very server-heavy way the only way? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how many games used a shared client/server model but it's probably a fair share of action games these days. Basically the server and client share most of the codebase and both simulate the game simultaneously (it helps if your methods are all deterministic, but it doesn't matter for things like graphical effects such as sparks/explosions, which don't affect the core gameplay)

The server sends updates to the client to tell it what's actually happening and the client corrects for errors. This is why in some action games when you have a network spike where you drop some packets, you can carry on running around shooting at people, and then suddenly the server re-establishes communications and puts you back where you were 5 seconds ago!

The server controls all important interactions such as loss of health, death etc so that you can't boost your health points by a billion whenever you feel like it

There's a good article here:

http://gamelix.com/resources/Unity3D%20Forum/Interpolation%20Explained.pdf

Which explains the old "server is boss" model and newer shared programming models with client-side prediction etc. It's a fair few years old but most of it still applies as far as I know.

Comment: I feared as much. Thank you for confirming, very helpful.

Comment: It also explains the way you can still shoot at bad guys who may have moved 250ms ago due to the ping times (using client side prediction - you shoot at what you see - you don't need to lead targets like you used to!)

Comment: It really depends on the game. You can either go with full simulation or even some approximation. In not really competitive games cheating is rare enough that you can make optimistic models like having a service which checks games and only later on pings user that he is cheater and ban him or do whatever you want with him. If this blocks you from release you should probably just make a game and if it is successful then make cheating protection which is good enough doesn't have to be perfect. Cheating is really show breaker for multiplayer games, but for this one I would be optimistic.